# How to calculate semantic similarity of short text corpora?

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, corpus

What is the proper approach to unsupervised comparison of semantic similarity between two short text corpora? Comparing LDA topic distributions for the two doesn't seem to be a solution, as for short documents the generated topics do not really grasp the semantics very well. Chunking didn't help, because  following tweets don't have to be on the same topic. Is e.g. creating a matrix of cosine similarities between document TF-IDFs in these corpora a good way to go?

Comment: What is your « unit » for comparison? Sentences? Paragraphs? Articles? Full documents?

Comment: Eventually, corpora. As for sub-units contributing to their scores, I'm not sure. Intuitively I'd go for keywords in documents. I don't know to what extent it's a good idea, though.

Comment: This is a very wide subject, and totally unsolved research topic. You could look into 
embeddings, or term frequency matrices, or just computing distances with document term matrices... Without an intuition (based on your data and expected high/low scores) it's very hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach found [here](https://nlpforhackers.io/wordnet-sentence-similarity/). The higher the similarity score, the closer the sentences are(semantically).

```py
#Invoke libraries
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn


#Build functions to compute similarity
def ptb_to_wn(tag):    
    if tag.startswith('N'):
        return 'n' 
    if tag.startswith('V'):
        return 'v' 
    if tag.startswith('J'):
        return 'a' 
    if tag.startswith('R'):
        return 'r' 
    return None


def tagged_to_synset(word, tag):
    wn_tag = ptb_to_wn(tag)
    if wn_tag is None:
        return None 
    try:
        return wn.synsets(word, wn_tag)[0]
    except:
        return None


def sentence_similarity(s1, s2):    
    s1 = pos_tag(word_tokenize(s1))
    s2 = pos_tag(word_tokenize(s2)) 

    synsets1 = [tagged_to_synset(*tagged_word) for tagged_word in s1]
    synsets2 = [tagged_to_synset(*tagged_word) for tagged_word in s2]

    #suppress "none"
    synsets1 = [ss for ss in synsets1 if ss]
    synsets2 = [ss for ss in synsets2 if ss]

    score, count = 0.0, 0

    for synset in synsets1:
        best_score = max([synset.path_similarity(ss) for ss in synsets2])
        if best_score is not None:
            score += best_score
            count += 1

    # Average the values
    score /= count
    return score

#compute the symmetric sentence similarity
def symSentSim(s1, s2):
    sss_score = (sentence_similarity(s1, s2) + sentence_similarity(s2,s1)) / 2
    return (sss_score)

s1 = 'We rented a vehicle to drive to New York'
s2 = 'The car broke down on our jouney'            

s1tos2 = symSentSim(s1, s2)

print(s1tos2)
#0.142509920635
```